# Unable to get the relieving letter

Tags: resignation, india, relieving-letter

When my father passed away I had to leave my job. It was very difficult finding a new job, but finally I got an offer from another company.

Things did not really work out at that second company, and I left (details below).

Now, after 4 months I have found a good job.

However, now if I have to get the appointment letter I have to get something as a proof from the second company. HR of that company and also the VP are not taking any interest in helping me.

**How can I get the appointment letter?**

---

Background history from that second company:

I only received an offer e-mail from them, which was never followed up by an official offer letter.

They collected a "security deposit" from me, to be reimbursed after a year. Later during the induction I was informed that salaries might be delayed for 2-3 months due to the company having a financial crisis. However, I had to continue working there or lose my security deposit. I was also the only source of income in my family.

The company had originally had its own bus I could travel on, but later the company sold this bus and I had to travel 30km to work. I also had to spend Rs. 100/- each day for the fuel, which I could not afford because they weren't paying me.

Three months passed without any pay and our family found it difficult to meet basic needs. We had taken a lot of loans out to cover my father's treatment and also after his death.

Because I wasn't being paid, I told the VP to whom I was reporting that I would not be continuing to work for this company any longer. (The offer e-mail had not mentioned any notice period.) I did this by SMS as I could not afford Rs. 20/- for a cyber cafe to send an e-mail.

Comment: Why not share this whole incident with the new hr with the emails you have and a single month salary slip if they have given or company id if you are provided. Please let us all know how it turned out

Comment: Show them the offer letter and explain them the sitiuation there telling them company has not paid you any salary for three months and why would it give you the experience letter. If you have any official email, send your resignation mail to them from that id BCC the HR of your new company. I worked in one company for 11 months and they did not give me relieving letter, my new company did not have any objection. Same will work for you as well.

Comment: Is "appointment letter" the same as "relieving letter"? Appointment letter sounds like it's given at the *start* of a job.

Comment: This story makes me feel sad. Your company has put you through a lot. While you are exploring other options, try posting your grievance here: http://pgportal.gov.in (Choose Ministry of Labour and Employment). I have tried this a couple of times with other Government Departments, and it has worked as a reasonable "out of court" settlement.

Comment: @Happy Thanks for the link, It is really a great effort by government. Will it be useful for non government employers as well like the one in OP's case ?

Comment: @aProgrammer Yes, absolutely. The private companies are also bound by the country's laws. If enough people from private companies complain to the Labour Ministry, they will take notice and the Government may bring in a law to regulate this relieving letter process. It is not enough if 3-4 people out of a workforce of several million complain, democracy doesn't work like that. :-)

Comment: @Happy Thanks for the explanation.. I just started spreading awareness about this portal. Out of this several million working population I am not sure how much actually know about the existence of such a system. We need to spread the word.

Comment: @aProgrammer You could update the wiki for the tag [tag:relieving-letter] with information about the site, and/or maybe create a canonical question and answer containing that info. That would make it easier for other people to find the information.

Answer (score 3):

While it is very sad and painful to read your story, I suggest very politely calling the VP or personally visiting the company one last time. Their you say that you need this letter for your career and see what they answer (if possible keep the audio/video recorder on). If they don't look positive, say, "Well in that case my lawyer will see you in court". I am sure in most cases companies want to avoid the courts and lawyers and in your case it is their fault. They should be ready for the settlement.

**Now, regardless of whether they give you letter or not you must go in labor court against these people and claim your salary. These unethical, unlawful activities must stop. If you don't drag them to court they will repeat same with someone else too.**

Answer (score -3):

Can't you just use the letter from the company before this one, and pretend you never worked at the truly terrible company you did, in fact, work for?

The relieving letters are not *mandatory* according to some website i googled (as in, they are not the Law), other people have mentioned (elsewhere on this site) that you can take this company to court to get them, although that is something a lawyer will tell you.

I would just pretend I never worked here and use the prior relieving letter myself.